# For routes with identical URI patterns, which is matched first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Assume a Rails application draws the following routes (i.e. this is what `rake routes` would show):

```
Verb  URI Pattern  Controller#Action
GET   /            one#show
GET   /            two#show
GET   /            three#show
```

What is the matching order for these routes when requesting the root path (i.e. `/`)? What factors detemine which route is matched first?

**Background**: I’m faced with a Rails application (Discourse) for which I’m writing a plugin. The Rails application sets up a bunch of root routes via `root to:` in its routes.rb file. My plugin tries to supply its own root route like this:

```
Discourse::Application.routes.append do
  root to: 'custom#show'
end
```

… adding a new route to the output from `rake routes`:

```
Verb  URI Pattern  Controller#Action
GET   /            one#show
GET   /            two#show
GET   /            three#show
GET   /            customshow
```

My problem is that I am not unable to make this new root take precedence over the other root routes. I tried using `prepend` instead of `append` which moves the custom root route to the top of the output, but it is still not matched first.

**Edit**: Presumably, routes are matched in the order they’re specified in, no matter the order from the `rake routes` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first matched route will be the one specified earlier in `routes.rb`.

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you
>   have a `resources :photos` above a get `'photos/poll'` the show action's
>   route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To
>   fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is
>   matched first.

Source: [link](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions), second note

Comment: Is there a way to have another route take precedence over the one that was specified first?

Comment: If the URI pattern is the same, then it is not possible.

Comment: I see. I wonder however, why when using `prepend` instead of `append` to add my route, the Rails logger claims that requesting the root path `/` is processed by `custom#show` when the result is that of `one#show` and `CustomController#show` is actually never called.