# Rails controller is not called but logger shows "Processing by controller…"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I’m writing a plugin for a Rails application (Discourse) and setup routes like this:

```
Discourse::Application.routes.append do
  root to: 'custom#show'
end
```

Unfortunately, the Rails application already defines a series of root routes in its `routes.rb` file. Since they’re specified first, they take precedence according to [“Rails Routing from the Outside In: 2.2 CRUD, Verbs, and Actions”](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

However, I noticed an odd logger entry when changing the route setup like this:

```
Discourse::Application.routes.prepend do
  root to: 'custom#show'
end
```

By using `prepend` instead of `append`, Rails’ logger output now claims this when requesting the root path `/`:

```
INFO -- : Started GET "/" …
INFO -- : Processing by CustomController#show as HTML
```

However, the action `CustomController#show` is not actually called. The application behaves exactly as before. How can I get Rails to call this controller and action instead just like the logger claims?

*(This is kind of a follow-up question to [“For routes with identical URI patterns, which is matched first?”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55278994/2036825))*

Answer (score 0):

Probably some kind of infinite look in your `before_action`s / `ApplicationController` / or the inherited Discourse controller.

You can debug it with logging statements and `Ctrl-C` during the request to see where is the hang (the stacktrace will appear).

Comment: It turns out it was something I dismissed to be the source: Discourse’s ApplicationController sets up a `check_xhr` before action which eventually leads to a different controller being invoked. The logging statement from Rails probably means “We expect this controller to be invoked” rather than it is currently being used.